# How to set papersize in Ubuntu?

Tags: printing, okular, adobe-reader

I am using Ubuntu Linux since a few years and there is one very ugly thing i came across a lot of time:

When trying to print okular and also via the command line (lpr) there is often a problem with regard to the correct papersize.

Often the printed pages are oversized for the paper, which coming out of my printer.

This has happend to me in different ubuntu versions and also on different printer (Mine: HP Officejet 6500709n and also on a Canon MG4250).

In my case I solved the problem via installing adobe reader (which is not always my favourit choice in linux due to adobe's bad linux support).When using Adobe reader the printed page is exactly that which shown in the printer menue within adobe reader. So the challenge seems to be to get okular or one of the others working too.

Any suggestions with regard to that problem?

PS: I normally install my printing drivers via

```
hp-setup <ip>
```

which is working greatly!

Comment: did you check these? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1921886 and https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=188878 ? (Found via google searches "ubuntu papersize" and "okular papersize" respectively)

Answer (score 0):

There may be a problem with the CUPS configuration for your printer.  To do this, open your printer configuration and change the "Page size" option, as follows:

Open System Settings > Printers > right-click your printer > Properties > Printer Options > Page size > choose your paper size.  Click OK.

Repeat this process for any other printers that seem to be trying to use the incorrect page size.

If you are unable to change your printer's settings this way, you may need to uninstall them and reinstall them using Ubuntu's printer configuration utility (in System Settings, as above).  HP drivers are normally included in Ubuntu by default, so unless your printers are exceptionally new, you shouldn't need to install additional software for them.

Comment: I tried to change the papersize in the system settings, but that didn't change a thing....As far as I know, the driver I use is the same as the standard one. But i could try to reinstall the printer (as soon as I have time).